# How to save and retrieve PDF file using room database

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I have saved files in my phone directory at this location `/storage/emulated/0/Papers/aw23xdr.pdf` I Want to add this file in room database and retrieve back.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: There are some uncertainties.
1. Why do you want to store files in DB?
2. How many files are you expecting to store there?

Answering these questions will help us provide you the most suitable solution.

Comment: 1) IN offline file is saved for syncing when net is available.  (2)It may be 15-20

Comment: This can be closed as "Needs Details Or Clarity".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing file directly you should store the PDF files in the file system of android(app specific local storage) and just save the file path in the Room DB.
BTW Room support BLOB storage in it so ideally you can convert file in bytes array and then store it in Room DB as a BLOB